# How do you add private members of one class to an array of a different class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, inheritance, private

I am relatively new to c++ and I have just learned how to use an array in a class, but I can't figure out how to add private members of one class to an array of a different class. I have a base class named collection, and a derived class called wallHangingType. When I try to input the length and width variable from wallHangingType into the array I get the error class collection has no member named 'length' or 'width'. I am required to have length and width in wallHangingType and not move them to the collection class. I would like to know how I would fix this to be able to input the length and width variables into the array.
collection.h

```
#ifndef COLLECTION_H
#define COLLECTION_H
#include <string>

class collection
{
    public:
        collection(int = 0, std::string = "NA", std::string = "NA");
        std::string getArtistName();
        std::string getTitle();
        void setTitle(std::string artTitle);
        void setArtist(std::string artist);
        void setId(int id);
        void print() const;

    private:
        std::string artistName;
        std::string title;
        int idNum;

};

#endif // COLLECTION_H
```

wallHangingType.h

```
#ifndef WALLHANGINGTYPE_H
#define WALLHANGINGTYPE_H
#include "collection.h"


class wallHangingType:public collection
{
    public:
        wallHangingType();
        void addPiece(int id, std::string name, std::string artTitle,int artLength, int artWidth);
        void removePiece();
        void printArt();

    private:
        int length;
        int width;
        collection pieces[100];
        int index;
};

#endif // WALLHANGINGTYPE_H
```

wallHangingType.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

wallHangingType::wallHangingType()
{
   index = 0;
}

void wallHangingType::addPiece(int id, std::string name, std::string artTitle,int artLength, int artWidth)
{
   pieces[index].setId(id);
   pieces[index].setArtist(name);
   pieces[index].setTitle(artTitle);
   pieces[index].length = artLength; //ERROR       
   pieces[index].width = artWidth;   //ERROR
}
```

Comment: `collection` indeed has no such members. Why would you expect them to exist, a `collection` is not a `wallHangingType`

Comment: Is there any way to place length and width into the pieces[index] from wallHangingType? the requirements said that I had to have length and width in the derived class, and so that is where I am having the problem. I can't find a way to place length and width into the array since the array isn't a wallHangingType. I don't even know if this way of doing it is possible.

Comment: You could have an array of pointers to `collection` and add `wallHangingType` pointers to that (created using `new`) - though that is a workaround for what seems to be a poorly designed requirement